# How to summarize a periodic signal in a few of index in order to rebuilt it again

Tags: r, signals, signal-processing

I have the periodic signal of 375 observations below:

[image]

and my objective is to extract some coefficient / information / etc in order to be able to exactly (or with a small error) re-generate it in the future without storing all the observations. Is there an easy way to do this thing in R? I tried a lot of different approaches but the results where far from what I need.

EDIT: The [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/91kpdsvh3o6fstp/DataStackOverflow.csv?dl=0).

Comment: Can you upload the data somewhere (Dropbox, gist.github.com, pastebin, etc.)? Also, *please* describe at least one method that you tried. My first instinct would be take FFT, and store the top N values and their respective bins. You also need to specify some reconstruction error tolerance, because that’ll govern what N is.

Comment: @AhmedFasih I tried FFT but I want to store less than N values since N could be very big and I want to save memory. My idea was to find like 10-12 coefficients in order to reproduce the first period of the signal and then repeat it as many times that I need it.
I added the Dropbox link with the data in the question.

Comment: If your data is periodic, then most of the FFT coefficients will be (close to) zero. So you’d only keep the big coefficients and their frequency bin. Let me look at your data to see if that’s a good fit. Also, the FFT is not the only basis one can use—you can also use any of the wavelet bases, e.g. The challenge here is, you’ve only given one signal, and we might find a good compressor for that, but not for other signals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to extract the top 10-20 peaks from a FFT? Depending on your signal, that could be sufficient (pay attention to the sampling rate,  the length of your file, etc.). This can be done this way:

```
library(pracma)
data <- read.csv('DataStackOverflow.csv', header=TRUE)
x <- data$x
z <- fft(x)
pks <- findpeaks(Mod(z), npeaks = 20, sortstr = TRUE)
```

The information is stored in pks[height, time].

```
X1 (height), X2 (time)
15.339362, 251
15.339362, 126
14.763523, 235
14.763523, 235
(...)
```

To run an inverse fft, replace the peaks + phase in an empty FT. I did it by removing unwanted data from z just for the example.

```
z [ Mod(z) < min(pks$X1) ] <- 0+0i
y <- fft(z, inverse = TRUE) / length(z)
```

[image: Original and new signals for npeaks in [10, 20, 60, 100]]

In order to store information, I assume that the findpeaks function itself with one period would be sufficient.

Comment: there is just one thing that I didn't understand: how can I rebuilt the original signal from the inverse fft? Because when I plot (for example) the y, the results are really far from the original signal.

Comment: The result of an inverse FFT is complex. Make sure you plot the real part of y: `Re(y)`.